# using Parameter overrides in SSIS Managed Object Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am using the managed Object Model to execute my SSIS 2012 packages.

I am trying to use `PackageInfo.PropertyOverrideParameterSet` to override connection string parameters that are automatically exposed in SSIS 2012.

SSIS `PackageInfo` class provides [an overloaded `Execute` method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh245662.aspx) that allows you to pass in Parameters you want overridden at run-time.  THis seems like a perfect opportunity to set connection strings.

To create a [`PackageInfo.PropertyOverrideParameterSet` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.aspx) however you need to specify the PropertyPath of the parameter you intend to override.

What format would that need to be in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a connection string can be done using [PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.executionvalueparameterset.aspx) instead of the [PackageInfo.PropertyOverrideParameterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.aspx).  The [ParameterName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.executionvalueparameterset.parametername.aspx) for a connection string would follow the format `CM.<connectionManagerName>.ConnectionString` (replace `<connectionManagerName>` with your connection manager name).  In the snippet below, my connection manager is named `B540P.KB1`).

```
PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet evps = new PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet();
evps.ParameterName = @"CM.B540P.KB1.ConnectionString";
evps.ParameterValue = @"Data Source=B540P;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=SSIS-Package1-{19035BA0-C90C-47AA-8AF6-31B025779FF6}B540P.KB1;";
evps.ObjectType = 30;

System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet> parms = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
parms.Add(evps);           

pkg.Execute(false, null, parms, null);
```

It may be possible to use [PackageInfo.PropertyOverrideParameterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.aspx) to set the connection string, but I'm not sure what the [PropertyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.propertypath.aspx) would be (see SQL Server link below for an example of a [PropertyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.propertypath.aspx) for an SSIS variable).

Here's some good information on interacting with MOM via different approaches:

- C# - [A Glimpse of the SSIS Catalog Managed Object Model - MSDN
  Blogs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/07/26/overview-of-the-ssis-mom.aspx&ei=FWm6UrrKDojrkAfEyYDwDg&usg=AFQjCNFk2HwhR7ITdn_6Q_km7XVWI-1mbw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.eW0)
- SQL Server - [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Integration Services](http://books.google.com/books?id=7MeZH75H7GoC&pg=RA6-PT311&lpg=RA6-PT311&dq=SSIS%20MOM%20execute%20package&source=bl&ots=-tVWP-4RLy&sig=9Laz9snqrDiq1m4sP_nmeCP4SIs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FWm6UrrKDojrkAfEyYDwDg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=SSIS%20MOM%20execute%20package&f=false)

  - Check out the **Property Overrides** section to see an example of setting the value of an SSIS Variable (it shows an example of a [PropertyPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.integrationservices.packageinfo.propertyoverrideparameterset.propertypath.aspx))
- Powershell - [SSIS and PowerShell in SQL Server 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/11/17/ssis-and-powershell-in-sql-server-2012.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was using ExecutionValueParameterSet to set SYNCHRONOUS running of the packages and didn't even think to use it for COnnectionStrings as well.  It seems to work well for package connection strings, but it can't seem to find Project level conneciton strings  which is what I'm after.  Must be misisng some qualifier?  I tried <projectname>.CM.<connection name.ConnectionString but to no avail.  Did you use this to set project level ConnectionStrings?  If so how?

Comment: Wow you can't make this stuff up.  While very useful MoM is so poorly documented.  So ObjectType=30 refers to package level objects while ObjectType=20 refers to Project level objects.  Changing that and I was good to go.  I made an edit to your answer and will mark it as correct.  This [Technet wiki article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21978.execute-ssis-2012-package-with-parameters-via-net.aspx) helped me realize my mistake.

Comment: by the way if you have a connection string which uses a username and password it seems you need to also set the username and password parameters in addition to the connection string. :-(