# How to see SSIS exception in my console log

Tags: powershell, ssis, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins slave of `windows server`. I'm running `SSIS` deploy command thought `Powershell`:

```
 $ISDeploymentWizard = Start-Process -FilePath ISDeploymentWizard.exe -ArgumentList '/Silent','/ModelType:Project','/SourcePath:"Integration Services\\bin\\Development\\Integration Services.ispac"',"/DestinationServer:${Env}",'/DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/TEST/DEVOPS"' -wait -PassThru -Credential $cred
    $ISDeploymentWizard.WaitForExit()
    $ISDeploymentWizard
```

The issue is when I have an error, I don't see anything in my `Jenkins` console as the `silent` mode is not working very well for `ISDeploymentWizard`. Any error in the syntax is causing a pop up window in the remote with the error. Is there any idea how can I make it appears also in my console? In the current situation, the job is just stuck at this stage, and I have to abort it manually.
I also tried to use `powershell` timeout, but it's not working as well. any idea?

The most relevant thread I've found is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/def8c8a5-9473-4e4d-8c4a-ecd71c035b3f/error-in-deploying-ispac-files-in-ssisdb-in-silent-mode?forum=sqlintegrationservices) one from 2015, and one alternative way suggested [here](https://joyfulcraftsmen.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/ssis-automated-deployment-for-project-mode/) also form 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISDeploymentWizard does what it does. It's a prebuilt executable and it appears you can't do much with the error handling.

I would advise taking a different approach and use the [Managed Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766091/using-parameter-overrides-in-ssis-managed-object-model) or a TSQL deploy route. That way, you can control what happens with your error conditions.

### Managed Object Model

My PS deploy code looked like this. It doesn't cover parameters and such but it's a start and you can try/catch the `DeployProject` portion

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices") | Out-Null

 
#this allows the debug messages to be shown
$DebugPreference = "Continue"

# Retrieves a 2012 Integration Services CatalogFolder object
# Creates one if not found
Function Get-CatalogFolder
{
    param
    (
        [string] $folderName
    ,   [string] $folderDescription
    ,   [string] $serverName = "localhost\dev2012"
    )

    $connectionString = [String]::Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;", $serverName)

    $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)

    $integrationServices = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.IntegrationServices($connection)
    # The one, the only SSISDB catalog
    $catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

    $catalogFolder = $catalog.Folders[$folderName]

    if (-not $catalogFolder)
    {
        Write-Debug([System.string]::Format("Creating folder {0}", $folderName))
        $catalogFolder = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.CatalogFolder($catalog, $folderName, $folderDescription)
        $catalogFolder.Create()
    }
    else
    {
        $catalogFolder.Description = "Modified for SO2"
        $catalogFolder.Alter()
        Write-Debug([System.string]::Format("Existing folder {0}", $folderName))
    }

    return $catalogFolder
}

# Deploy an ispac file into the SSISDB catalog
Function Deploy-Project
{
    param
    (
        [string] $projectPath
    ,   [string] $projectName
    ,   $catalogFolder
    )

    # test to ensure file exists
    if (-not $projectPath -or  -not (Test-Path $projectPath))
    {
        Write-Debug("File not found $projectPath")
        return
    }

    Write-Debug($catalogFolder.Name)
    Write-Debug("Deploying $projectPath")

    # read the data into a byte array
    [byte[]] $projectStream = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($projectPath)

    # $ProjectName MUST match the value in the .ispac file
    # else you will see 
    # Failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again later.:The specified project name, test, does not match the project name in the deployment file.
    $projectName = "HR Import Raw"
    $projectName = "SSIS2012"

    $project = $catalogFolder.DeployProject($projectName, $projectStream)
}


$isPac = "C:\Dropbox\Sandbox\SSIS2012\SSIS2012\bin\DEV2012\SSIS2012.ispac"
$folderName = "SSIS2012"
$folderDescription = "Prod deployment check"

$serverName = "localhost\dev2012"

$catalogFolder = Get-CatalogFolder $folderName $folderDescription $serverName

Deploy-Project $isPac $projectName $catalogFolder
```

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/a-glimpse-of-the-ssis-catalog-managed-object-model/ba-p/387892

### TSQL Deploy

```
DECLARE
    @folder_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @folder_id bigint = NULL
,   @project_name nvarchar(128) = 'TSQLDeploy'
,   @project_stream varbinary(max)
,   @operation_id bigint = NULL;

-- Read the zip (ispac) data in from the source file
SELECT
    @project_stream = T.stream
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\sandbox\SSDTDeploy\TSQLDeploy\bin\Development\TSQLDeploy.ispac', SINGLE_BLOB ) AS B
) AS T (stream);

-- Test for catalog existences
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        CF.name
    FROM
        catalog.folders AS CF
    WHERE
        CF.name = @folder_name
)
BEGIN
    -- Create the folder for our project
    EXECUTE [catalog].[create_folder] 
        @folder_name
    ,   @folder_id OUTPUT;
END

-- Actually deploy the project
EXECUTE [catalog].[deploy_project] 
    @folder_name
,   @project_name
,   @project_stream
,   @operation_id OUTPUT;

-- Check to see if something went awry
SELECT
    OM.* 
FROM
    catalog.operation_messages AS OM
WHERE
    OM.operation_id = @operation_id;
```

I assume jenkins allows for PS or sql commands so these should work and give you more flexibility with regard to detecting deployment issues and then resolving them.